# QUERY with Week Number

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-filter

I use query to extract two columns from another sheet with data.

- Column A has dates
- Column B - numbers

I want to extract only rows that correspond to a specific calendar week number. For example 19.
I use this query

```
=query(Database!A1:AD,"Select A,AB where WEEKNUM(A)=19",1)
```

But it returns `#VALUE` error. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**`weeknum`** is not a valid **[scalar function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar-functions)** so you need to trick it like this:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:B, WEEKNUM(A2:A)}, "where Col3 = 21")), 999^99, 2)
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=FILTER(A2:B, WEEKNUM(A2:A)=21)
```

[image: 0]